# What is the most efficient way to initialize an array with values?

Tags: java, arrays

I need to create an int array of a specific size. The array should be initialized with a specific, non-0 value (all elements should be 1).

```
int[] array = createArray(12, 1);
```

Of course I could simply initialize the array and for-loop over it, setting all values to 1.

```
int[] createArray(int size, int defaultValue){
   int[] arr = new int[size];
   for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
       arr[i] = defaultValue;
   }
   return arr;
}
```

But I wonder, if there are better alternatives (i.e. Java out-of-the box utilities) to this in terms of speed or compactness of source code so I could potentially inline it instead of having a dedicated method for that?

Comment: Use Arrays.fill

Comment: I am wondering why an user of your experience didnt do research prior asking a question ;-)

Comment: I did, but I didn't know about `Arrays.fill` before and therefore wasn't explicity searching for _fill_ and the list of related questions for "what is the most efficient way" didn't bring this up. The search is sometimes not really helpful unless you already know what you want to find. But anyway, thanks for providing the link.